# UNIX:Create array from space delimited string while ignoring space in quotes

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to create an array from a space delimited string, this works fine till i have to ignore the space within double quotes for splitting the string.

I Tried:

```
inp='ROLE_NAME="Business Manager" ROLE_ID=67686'

arr=($(echo $inp | awk -F" " '{$1=$1; print}'))
```

This splits the array like:

```
${arr[0]}: ROLE_NAME=Business
${arr[1]}: Manager
${arr[2]}: ROLE_ID=67686
```

when actually i want it:

```
${arr[0]}: ROLE_NAME=Business Manager
${arr[1]}: ROLE_ID=67686
```

Im not really good with awk so can't figure out how to fix it.
Thanks

Comment: Your `awk` is essentially a *no-op* here.  You'll get similar results without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bash specific, may work with ksh/zsh

```
inp='ROLE_NAME="Business Manager" ROLE_ID=67686'
set -- $inp
arr=()
while (( $# > 0 )); do
    word=$1
    shift
    # count the number of quotes
    tmp=${word//[^\"]/}
    if (( ${#tmp}%2 == 1 )); then
        # if the word has an odd number of quotes, join it with the next
        # word, re-set the positional parameters and keep looping
        word+=" $1"
        shift
        set -- "$word" "$@"
    else
        # this word has zero or an even number of quotes.
        # add it to the array and continue with the next word
        arr+=("$word")
    fi
done

for i in ${!arr[@]}; do printf "%d\t%s\n" $i "${arr[i]}"; done
```

```
0   ROLE_NAME="Business Manager"
1   ROLE_ID=67686
```

This specifically breaks words on arbitrary whitespace but joins with a single space, so your custom whitespace within quotes will be lost.